# Prove that $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$ is not a UFD

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, elliptic-curves

*I am posting this question on MO since I haven't received any answers on MSE.*

Below is my (very elementary) attempt. Feel free to post a solution using facts in algebraic geometry and facts about elliptic curves.

Start by noticing $x^3=(1-y)(1+y+y^2)$ in $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$. I am trying to show first that $x$ is irreducible modulo $(x^3+y^3-1)$.

Every polynomial in $\Bbb C[x,y]$ is of the form $$p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2+r(x,y)(x^3+y^3-1)$$ for some polynomials $p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x),r(x,y)$ in $\Bbb C[x,y]$. So that given $$x=(p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2)(q_1(x)+q_2(x)y+q_3(x)y^2)+r(x,y)(x^3+y^3-1)$$ one needs to show that either $q_1(x)+q_2(x)y+q_3(x)y^2$ or $p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2$ is a unit modulo $(x^3+y^3-1)$, i.e for example $$(p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2)f(x,y) = k+g(x,y)(x^3+y^3-1)$$ for some constant $k$ and polynomials $f,g\in\Bbb C[x,y]$ is the same as saying $p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2$ is a unit modulo $(x^3+y^3-1)$.

This gets extremely messy afterwards. Is there a better way I could approach this?

Comment: Please see [here on meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5012/can-i-ask-a-question-on-mathoverflow-and-also-on-another-site) for discussion about cross-posting between MO and MSE. ([Here is a link to the MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801913/prove-that-x-is-irreducible-in-bbb-cx-y-x3y3-1).)

Comment: Yes, if you know a bit of algebraic geometry: you are asking about the Picard group of an elliptic curve minus 3 points — this is indeed very large.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a relatively clean proof that doesn't involve knowing that this is the coordinate ring of a positive genus curve.

Comment: I have been wondering about this myself, especially in comparison with [the related example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/ring-of-trigonometric-functions-with-real-coefficients) of the ring ${\mathbb C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$, which is a UFD; this has an elementary proof, but also another proof that studies the Picard group of the corresponding punctured curve.

Comment: ...what appears very interesting to me is that the question of the rings being UFD should somehow be related to whether the corresponding curves have rational parametrisations: $\{x^2+y^2=1\}\subset{\mathbb C}^2$ of course does (elementary, project from any point), whereas $\{x^3+y^3=1\}\subset{\mathbb C}^2$ does not; the latter also admits an elementary proof (involving infinite descent). This is the other well-known shadow of the effect of genus.

Comment: ...I have also been pondering the fact that the real story diverges: ${\mathbb R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is not a UFD, the real curve has a non-trivial class group, but $\{x^2+y^2=1\}\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ still admits a rational parametrisation (indeed any base field works), since it has obvious real points.

Comment: Both $x$ and $x^3+y^3+1$ vanish at the point $(0,1)$ hence one of the factors also must vanish there. Perhaps it's easier to expand polynomials in a Taylor series around $(0,1)$ instead of the origin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a proof using a bit of commutative algebra and algebraic geometry, elaborating on comments by @abx and @ChrisWuthrich. The ring
$$R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$$
is a Dedekind domain, because it is the coordinate ring of the affine elliptic curve
$$E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2:x^3+y^3=1\}.$$
As a result, if $R$ is a UFD, then it is also a PID, hence the Picard group $\mathrm{Pic}(E)$ is trivial. We shall show that this is not the case.

Consider the projective closure of $E$:
$$\tilde E=\{(x:y:z)\in\mathbf{P}(\mathbb{C}^3):x^3+y^3=z^3\}.$$
We have an embedding $f:E\to\tilde E$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,1)$, and in fact $\tilde E$ is the disjoint union of $f(E)$ and the set of points at infinity,
$$S=\{(-1:1:0), (-1:e^{2\pi i/3}:0), (-1:e^{4\pi i/3}:0)\}.$$
Restricting divisors of $\tilde E$ to $f(E)=\tilde E\setminus S$ gives rise to an exact sequence
$$0\to\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde E,S)\to\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde E)\to\mathrm{Pic}(E)\to 0,$$
where $\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde E,S)$ is the group of divisors of $\tilde E$ supported on $S$ modulo principal divisors of $\tilde E$ supported on $S$. Note that $\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde E,S)$ is a finitely generated abelian group, while $\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde E)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\tilde E$ if we regard $\tilde E$ as an abelian group in the usual way. Hence $\mathrm{Pic}(E)$ has cardinality continuum, and $R$ is not a UFD.

**Remark 1.** The field $L=\mathbb{C}(x,y)/(x^3+y^3-1)$ is a cubic Galois extension of $K=\mathbb{C}(x)$. The ideal $(x)$ of $R$ factors into prime ideals as
$$(x)=(x,y-1)(x,y-e^{2\pi i/3})(x,y-e^{4\pi i/3}),$$
and the three factors are cyclically permuted by $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$. In fact these factors are not principal as the answer of user516477 shows below. Equivalently, $x$ is irreducible (but not prime) in $R$.

**Remark 2.** Note that $x+y$, $x+e^{2\pi/3}y$, $x+e^{4\pi/3}y$ are units in $R$ as their product is $x^3+y^3=1$. It can be derived from the calculations of user516477 that these three units and $\mathbb{C}^\times$ generate $R^\times$. It follows that $\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde E,S)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/3)$, and $\mathrm{Pic}(E)$ is isomorphic to $\tilde E$ divided by a certain 3-element subgroup.

Comment: What is $O$ here?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich $O$ is the point at infinity, i.e. the neutral element, of the projectivization of $E$ (which is also an abelian group).

Comment: It might be nice to say what its class group is, as that would give information as to exactly how non-UFD it is.

Comment: @GHfromMO But there are *three* points at infinity for this curve. I know you are trying to take the proof of what the Jacobian of the projective closure is and get the minimal part of it to show that the ring is non PID. But I believe you need to be more careful here.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I fixed it, please have a look.

Comment: I feel like, while it's useful to determine the class group, this answer uses a sledgehammer to circumvent a more basic question: what's an example of non-unique factorization in the given Dedekind domain.

Comment: ..or, in the spirit of the OP's question, an example of an irreducible that is not prime.

Comment: Maybe one can show directly here, using divisors on $E$, that the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$ associated to $P=(1,0)$ is not principal.

Comment: When you say $(x,y-1)^3 = (x^3,(y-1)^3)$ can you please give a hint why that is true? Perhaps it is obvious, but I am not seeing why the $x^2(y-1)$ and $x(y-1)^2$ are apparently redundant.

Comment: @ZachTeitler In every Dedekind domain, it is true for any nonzero ideals $I$ and $J$ that $\gcd(I,J)^n=\gcd(I^n,J^n)$. But here is a more direct proof. The ideal $(x,y-1)^3$ contains $x^3$ and $(y-1)^3$, hence it also contains $(x^3,(y-1)^3)=(y-1)$. On the other hand, $(x,y-1)^3$ is clearly generated by the four elements $x^3$, $x^2(y-1)$, $x(y-1)^2$, $(y-1)^3$, each of which lies in $(y-1)$. So $(x,y-1)^3$ is contained in $(y-1)$, and we are done.

Comment: It is very nice! Thank you.

Comment: This is great. What I find remarkable about this last proof is that it is basically the same proof as the insolubility of the Fermat cubic over ${\mathbb Z}$, except that it has a different conclusion; note that proof would run in ${\mathbb Z}[\omega]$ which... is a UFD.

Comment: With all explicit proofs, I have some doubts. They should not work for $x^2+y^2-1$. They should not work when the curve has a singularity. $(x,y-1)=(y-1)^3$ is because this is an inflection point on the curve, but singular curves could have an inflection point....

Comment: @Balazs Unfortunately, the short proof in the "Added" section was not complete, but we have now a very nice argument by user516477.

Answer (score 4):

There are likely more-elementary approaches, but here is an argument using some basic function-field arithmetic. Let's work a bit more generally than in the original question, considering a base field $F$, not of characteristic $3$. Let $R$ be the ring $F[x,y] / (x^3 + y^3 - 1)$, and let $L$ be the fraction field of $R$. Let's assume furthermore that $F$ contains an element $\omega$ that is a primitive cube root of $1$. We will show that $R$ is not a UFD by showing that the ideal $(x, y - 1)$ is not principal.

The ring $R$ has three evident units, $\eta_1 = x + y$, $\eta_2 = \omega x + y$, and $\eta_3 = \omega^2 x + y$, satisfying $\eta_1 \eta_2 \eta_3 = 1$. This rank-$2$ group of units complicates the arithmetic of $R$, as discussion in comments elsewhere noted. The field $L$ is something like a totally real cubic number field. (If $F$ did not contain a primitive cube root of $1$, then we would only have a rank-$1$ group of units, and the arithmetic would be simpler. The field $L$ would be something like a cubic number field with one real and one complex infinite place.)

The function field $L$ over $F$ has three infinite places (where the valuation of $x$ is negative), all of which have degree $1$. We can describe these places explicitly using the coordinates $u = 1/x$ and $v = y/x$. The infinite places are $P = (u, v + 1)$, $Q = (u, v + \omega)$, and $R = (u, v + \omega^2)$. Using these places, we find that the divisor of $\eta_1$ is $2P - Q - R$; that the divisor of $\eta_2$ is $-P + 2Q - R$; and that the divisor of $\eta_3$ is $-P-Q+2R$. As a consequence of these divisor calculations, we have $2P - Q \sim R$ and $3P \sim 3Q$, where $\sim$ denotes linear equivalence of divisors in the function field $L$ over $F$.

Let $T$ be a degree-$1$ place of $L$, and suppose that we have $T \sim aP + bQ + cR$ for some integers $a, b, c$, where $\sim$ denotes linear equivalence of divisors in $L$ as above. A bit of algebra with the divisors of the $\eta_i$ shows that $T$ is equivalent to one of $P, Q, R$. Indeed, using $-P + 2Q \sim R$, we can eliminate $R$ to get $T \sim a'P + b'Q$. Using $3P \sim 3Q$, we then have $T \sim a'' P + b''Q$, where $b''$ is $0, 1,$ or $-1$. Since the total degree of $a''P + b''Q$ is $1$, in the first case we have $T \sim P$. In the same way, the second case gives $T \sim Q$, and, using $2P - Q \sim R$, the third case gives $T \sim R$.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $R$ whose residue field is $F$, such as $(x, y - 1)$. We show that $\mathfrak{p}$ is not principal. Suppose for contradiction that $\mathfrak{p}$ were principal, generated by an element $f$ of $R$. The divisor of $f$ would then be $T - (aP + bQ + cR)$, where $T$ is the degree-$1$ place of $L$ corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}$, and where $a,b,c$ are suitable integers. By the argument above, we could then conclude that one of $T\sim P$, $T \sim Q$, or $T\sim R$ holds. Since $T$ is a finite place, it is distinct from the three infinite places, and so these linear equivalences are impossible, as the genus of $L$ is $1$.

(There are various ways to see that these linear equivalences are impossible. Suppose, for example, that $g$ were an element of $L$ with divisor $T - P$. Then the $1$-form $g \frac{dx}{y^2}$ would have a single singularity, a simple pole at $P$ with non-zero residue. But this is impossible, since the sum of residues of a meromorphic differential for $L$ must be $0$.)

Comment: Very nice argument. It also follows along these lines that $R^\times$ is generated by $\mathbb{C}^\times$ and the exhibited units $\eta_j$. Indeed, the divisors $\mathrm{div}(\eta_j)$ generate an index $3$ subgroup in the group of degree zero divisors supported on $\{P,Q,R\}$, with cosets being represented by the divisors $0$, $Q-R$, $R-Q$. However, $Q\not\sim R$, whence the subgroup in question is the group of all principal divisors supported on $\{P,Q,R\}$. This also shows that $\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde E,S)$ in my post is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/3)$.